# Timeseries analysis on current data

Tags: time-series, outliers

Please forgive the newbie nature of this question, but I'm really struggling with Mr Google.

The vast majority of resources I can find on time-series analysis seem to be concerned with the Holy Grail of forecasting the future. But I couldn't be less interested in that.

What I'm really looking for (and hence would appreciate pointers in the right direction in terms of techniques and methodology) is analysis of current and historic time-series data. I believe the overall concept here is outliers but I'm really struggling to find good timeseries examples due to the internet focus on forecasting the future.

For example, let's say I've got a time series of identities and I'm essentially looking for needles in haystacks, for example:

- Identifying "rare" identities
- Identifying "beaconing" (intermittent repetitive reappearance, either same timeframe or random)
- Identifying changes in frequency of identities

Basically trying to identify "things" hiding in the "noise".

I have seen references to unsupervised machine learning being required for this sort of thing. My problem with machine learning is that it typically needs a human-made good/bad training dataset which I won't have.

Comment: What is a matrix profile? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8594928

Comment: @NikolasRieble Its amazing how easy it is to find things once you know what you're looking for.  Mr Google is much more helpful given the words "matrix profile", the CS UCR page is particularly interesting and has a good examples PDF.  Thank you !

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find time to write a proper answer - I might do it later. I still wanted to share what I know. If you find time to write a proper answer yourself that would also be great.